# data through ajax for tagify whitelist

Tags: javascript, ajax, tagify

I'm trying to get the data through ajax for tagify whitelist. but I get the following mistake

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: clist
```

code is:

```
$.ajax({
                url: '/ajaxget/tags',
                method: 'GET',
                data: {
                    <?= csrf_token() ?> : '<?=csrf_hash()?>'
                },
                success: function(response) {
                 var clist = response;
                    //alert(response);
                }
            });


    var input = document.querySelector('input[name="tags"]');

    tagify = new Tagify(input, {
        enforceWhitelist: true,
      whitelist: clist,
      maxTags: 5,
      dropdown: {
        maxItems: 5,           
        classname: "tags-look", 
        enabled: 0,             
        closeOnSelect: false    
      }
    });
```

when I test it with "alert (response);" displays the data - `['123','333','763',asd']`

Comment: As the error message says. You're using a variable named `clist` (in `whitelist: clist,`) but you're never defining that variable

Comment: `var clist` is defined inside `success: function(response)` and therefore is only accessible within this function. Declare it outside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to access a local variable from callback response as global variable.

```
             $.ajax({
                url: '/ajaxget/tags',
                method: 'GET',
                data: {
                    <?= csrf_token() ?> : '<?=csrf_hash()?>'
                },
                success: function(response) {
                 var clist = response;
                    populateList(clist);
                }
            });

    function populateList(clist) {
      var input = document.querySelector('input[name="tags"]');

      tagify = new Tagify(input, {
        enforceWhitelist: true,
        whitelist: clist,
        maxTags: 5,
        dropdown: {
          maxItems: 5,           
          classname: "tags-look", 
          enabled: 0,             
          closeOnSelect: false    
        }
      });
  }
```

Comment: Thank you, but now it get everything as one parameter and does not divide them into separate ones. show this ``` '123','333','763',asd'``` the right thing is ```123``` ```333``` ... does not recognize that it is json

Comment: You need to parse the json before using. Do var clist = JSON.parse(response);